# Changing Function Domain of Fourier Series

Tags: functions, fourier-analysis

If I write
    FourierSinSeries[x, x, 10]

Mathematica will output the first 10 terms of the Fourier Sine Series f(x) = x defined for 0 < x < Pi.

How do I output the the Fourier Sine Series for a different domain, say 0 < x < 2 Pi?

Comment: You can try my `easyFourierSinSeries`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149469/1871

Answer (score 5):

Use `{a,b}`->`{1,1/2}` for `FourierParameters`

```
      FourierSinSeries[x, x, 10, FourierParameters -> {1, 1/2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is because the [Fourier sine series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_sine_and_cosine_series) is defined as $b_k= \frac{2}{L} \int_0^L  f(x) \sin\left( \frac{k \pi x}{L}  \right) dx$ and Mathematica uses

[image: Mathematica graphics]

so for $L=2\pi$, if we use $b=\frac{1}{2}$ and $a=1$ then Mathematica definition becomes $b_k= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}  f(x) \sin\left( \frac{k x}{2}  \right) dx$ which is what you get when $L=2\pi$