# Fourier series of an arbitrary periodic piecewise function

Tags: fourier-analysis, piecewise

Let's take a switch function as an example:
    $  
u(t)=
\begin{cases} 
1,  &  \text{$0<t<dT_s$} \\ 
0,  &  \text{$dT_s<t<T_s$}
\end{cases}
$
How can I get Fourier series of it in Mathematica?
Is there a way to get Fourier series of arbitrary periodic piecewise function?

Comment: I would start by having a look at `Piecewise` and `Fourier`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks You probably meant `FourierSeries`, right? `Fourier` is the discrete fourier transform (FFT). I am also puzzeld by the many different Fourier-related commands in _Mathematica_.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Indeed, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149468/1871

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 2):

for example:

```
u[t_] = Piecewise[{{1, 0 < t < dT}, {0, dT < t < T}}];
FourierTrigSeries[u[t], t, 3, FourierParameters -> {1, 2 \[Pi]/T}, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < dT < T && 2 dT == T]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `u[t_] := UnitStep[Sin[t]];
FourierSeries[u[x], x, 3]` 3 is series

Comment: One might want to be mindful of the `FourierParameters` setting when using `FourierSeries[]` and other sundry functions, lest *Mathematica*'s chosen normalization might not be the same as your preferred one.