# Strange result of FourierCosCoefficient on $\cos^2 t$

Tags: bugs, fourier-analysis

The following strange answers were just reported in [Mathematics.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3141024/11619). The OP was asking about the Fourier cosine series of the function
$$\cos^2t=\frac12(1+\cos 2t).$$

That question is about WA, but Mathematica (mine is version 11) gives the outputs:

```
In[1]:=FourierCosCoefficient[Cos[t]^2, t, n]
Out[1]:=0 
In[2]:=FourierCosCoefficient[(1+Cos[2t])/2, t, n]
Out[2]:=1/2 (DiscreteDelta[-2 + n] + 2 DiscreteDelta[n])
```

I assume we all know that the second output is correct, and the first is wrong.

Can somebody shed more light to this?

Comment: clearly this is a bug.  You can submit a bug report to wolfram@support.com

Comment: Can someone try for other powers of cosine? How about `FourierSinCoefficient[]` and powers of sine?

Comment: A great idea, @J.M.iscomputer-less! `FourierSinCoefficient[Sin[t]^3, t, n]` also gives output $0$. The same with the fifth power of sine and the fourth power of cosine (for the respective sine/cosine series).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen fyi, this is Maple's output  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rB8HE.png)

Comment: Interestingly, `FourierCosCoefficient[1/2 + 1/2 Cos[2 t], t, n]` (so, with `(1+Cos[2t])/2` expanded) also gives 0. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: This gets the right answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149469/4999

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. See the tag description for why.  (I won't remove it because there is already clear agreement that this is a bug but next time please don't add it yourself _to your own question_. Do itt it to others' questions when there is clearly a bug.)

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice, @Szabolcs. Noted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[@user64494](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7152/user64494) is correct that the result arises because some of *Mathematica's* solvers return results that are only generically correct (that is, incorrect only for finitely many exceptions or on a manifold of dimension lower than the dimension of the domain of the problem).  Clearly (I think it's clear), WRI does not consider all such behavior a bug.  However, users may well feel that such behavior is undesirable and may insist on calling it a bug.  I can explain where the "genericity problem" arises in this example.

`FourierCosCoefficient` works by first trying table lookup, which succeeds when the expression is in Fourier-series form (e.g. the OP's second example).  When table lookup fails, it tries `Integrate`.  Here the problem comes from integrals like this one, which is only generically true (for `n != 0`):

```
Integrate[Cos[n t], t]
(*  Sin[n t]/n  *)
```

This leads to limits of such functions at `t -> Pi`,
which gives the result `0`, which again is incorrect for `n == 0`. 
One can get around this specific problem by using the identity $\sin x = x \mathop{\text{sinc}} x$. 
For example:

```
Limit[Sin[n t]/n, t -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow", Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
(*  0  *)

Limit[Sin[n t]/n /. Sin -> (# Sinc[#] &), t -> Pi, Direction -> "FromBelow",
  Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers]
(*  π Sinc[n π]  *)
```

We can use the [Villegas-Gayley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2795/4999) trick to catch `Limit` and apply the identity:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Limit},
 Unprotect[Limit];
 Limit[f_, args__] /; ! TrueQ[$in] := Block[{$in = True},
   Limit[f /. Sin -> (# Sinc[#] &), args]];
 Protect[Limit];
 FourierCosCoefficient[Cos[t]^2, t, n]
 ]
(*  1/2 (Sinc[(-2 + n) π] + 2 Sinc[n π] + Sinc[(2 + n) π])  *)

FunctionExpand[%, Assumptions -> n ∈ Integers] // InputForm
(*  (KroneckerDelta[2 - n] + 2*KroneckerDelta[n] + KroneckerDelta[2 + n])/2  *)

Table[%, {n, 0, 5}]
(*  {1, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0}  *)
```

I'm pretty sure you don't always want to replace all the sines by sincs, but I think it shows what is going on in the OP's examples.

Comment: This is neat. How did you figure out that `Limit[]` was the culprit?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less `Trace[code, _f, TraceInternal -> True]` with `f` equal to `Integrate` and `Limit` got me started. I just thought I'd try to see if *M* did what I would do by hand.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a bug: Mathematica produces a generic answer by default and most of the coefficients equal zero. The Fourier expansion of `Cos[2t]`  is produced by

```
FourierCosSeries[Cos[t]^2, t, 5]
```

> $\frac{1}{2} \cos (2 t)+\frac{1}{2} $

Comment: Thanks for testing this. Yet, I think the real question is why `Cos[t]^2` and `(1+Cos[2t])/2` give different answers. I would think that the generic answers for both would be the same.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: The command FourierCosCoefficient[1/2 + Cos[2 t]/2, t, n] // Simplify also produces 0.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: I'd like to add that the results of FourierCoefficient[(1 + Cos[2 t])/2, t, n] and FourierCoefficient[(Cos[ t]^2, t, n] coincide.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen: Up to the help, the FourierCosCoefficient is aimed at basic functions Cos[n*t]. The FourierCosCoefficient command does not do any trig transforms in most of cases.. I think this makes the difference asked in your question

Comment: Why would *trig transforms* (assuming you mean applications of trig identities) make any difference whatsoever? According to Mathematica help `FourierCosCoefficient[f,t,n]` calculates the integral
$$\frac2{\pi}\int_{t=0}^\pi f(t)\cos nt\,dt.$$ It should not matter whether trig identities are applied or not. The integral is still the same.

Comment: @Jyrki Lehtonen: As we see that statement in the Mathematica help is not true.