# Is simplify giving a "not always" correct answer here?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

A result like this appears as one of the terms when I compute coefficients in a Fourier Series:

```
expr =(Sin[n*Pi])/((-4 + n^2))
```

If I simplify all my terms, this happens:

```
Simplify[expr, Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]] (*returns a zero*)
```

Which is true except if n=-2 or 2:

```
Limit[expr, n -> 2] (*give Pi/4*)
```

Shouldn't Simplify catching that?

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192933)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

From the "Possible Issues" section of the documentation for [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html), "results of simplification of expressions with singularities are uncertain"

```
expr = (Sin[n*Pi])/((-4 + n^2));
```

The general result would be

```
expr = Module[{
   roots = n /. Solve[Denominator[expr] == 0, n]},
  Simplify[
   Piecewise[{
     {expr, And @@ Thread[roots != n]},
     Sequence @@ ({Limit[expr, n -> #], n == #} & /@ roots)}],
   Element[n, Integers]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Yup. I should have looked at Possible Issues before posting. Thanks @BobHanlon.