# How to symbolically manipulate the closed form series output from the easyFourier package?

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis

[EasyFourier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149468/a-more-convenient-fourier-series) by @xzczd is a nice package to obtain a Fourier series in closed form, e.g.

```
f = x^2
easyFourierTrigSeries[f, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, \[Infinity]]
```

[image]

However, the output cannot be manipulated symbolically, at least I don't know how to. For instance, differentiating the Fourier series is not possible like this:

```
D[easyFourierTrigSeries[f, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, \[Infinity]],x]
```

[image]

What I would like to do is something comparable to the following, where I have copied the summand manually into a regular Mathematica *Sum*:

[image]

BTW: How do I downscale the size of pictures in stack exchange? Is there no easier way to insert Mathematica output? How can I insert complicated Mathematica input code in 2d-mode? (Thanks for hints to these "meta" questions, too.)

Comment: Perhaps ``ReleaseHold``? ``D[ReleaseHold@easyFourierTrigSeries[f, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, \[Infinity]], x]`` gives ``2 (I Log[1 + E^(-I x)] - I Log[1 + E^(I x)])``.

Comment: @Domen, that's the evaluated form. What I need is the Out[94].

Comment: I have provided an answer. As for the images: you can change the size of the image on StackExchange by using pure html tag as described in the [Advanced Markdown help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images). Furthermore, [SE-Tools](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/new-se-tools-formerly-known-as-se-uploader) is a really nice tool to quickly upload images from Mathematica to SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Inactivate` has attribute `HoldFirst`, that is why `Inactivate[ft, Sum]` by itself doesn't inactivate your sum. You have to first bypass this HoldFirst with `Evaluate`.

```
ft = easyFourierTrigSeries[f, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, \[Infinity]]
D[Inactivate[Evaluate[ft], Sum] // ReleaseHold, x]

(* Inactive[Sum][-((
  4 (-1)^\[FormalK] Sin[\[FormalK] x])/\[FormalK]), {\[FormalK], 
  1, \[Infinity]}] *)
```

Let's take a look at some of the examples to better understand how `Inactivate` works:

```
5 + 3
(* 8 *)

Inactivate[5 + 3, Plus]
(* Inactive[Plus][5, 3] *)

Activate[Inactivate[5 + 3, Plus], Plus]
(* 8 *)

x = Hold[5 + 3]
(* Hold[5 + 3] *)

Inactivate[x, Plus]
(* Hold[5 + 3] *)

Inactivate[Hold[5 + 3], Plus] 
(* Hold[Inactive[Plus][5, 3]] *)

Inactivate[Evaluate[Hold[5 + 3]], Plus]
(* Hold[Inactive[Plus][5, 3]] *)
```

As you can see in the fifth example, `Inactivate` cannot penetrate inside `x` and "see" that there is a `Plus` (because it has attribute `HoldFirst`), so it doesn't inactivate it.

If you look at the documentation of `Evaluate`, it says: *You can use `Evaluate` to override `HoldFirst` etc. attributes of built-in functions.* And this is exactly what we need in this case: we use evaluate, but this doesn't mean that `5 + 3` will instantly be replaced with `8`. Instead, `Inactivate` will be able to creep inside `x` and inactivate `Plus`.

Comment: Great, that is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks also for your hints on the meta issues.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Mathematica yet, and I have problems understanding why your solution works. Why does the Holdfirst attribute prevent Inactivate to work properly in this case (normally it does not)? And why do we therefore need Evaluate? This seems highly contradictory, since what we want is ft *not* to be evaluated, but to be inactivated. Can you possibly explain that in a few more words?

Comment: Thank you very much, I see the point now!