# How to calculate Fourier series for an arbitray non-periodic function defined in arbitray interval by setting FourierParemters or by rescale? How?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am struggling to understand the Fourier series in Mathematica.

I don't find a way to calculate Fourier series for a general function which is not periodic and defined on a interval but not on typical inervals like `[-Pi, Pi]` as required by `FourierSeries` command. For example like a function shown below.

My first naive idea to use `FourierParameters` option of `FourierSeries`, but I don't know how to set them.

I search the forum for my problem. I saw the great answer by xzczd who invented [`easyFourier`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149468/a-more-convenient-fourier-series) , but that is too much programming for me.

```
func[x_] := Piecewise[{{x, 1 <= x < 2}, {1, 2 <= x <= 3}}, Undefined]
Plot[func[x], {x, 0, 4}]
```

[image]

Thanks in advance! :)

**======================= Update 1 ============================**

Thanks to the helpful comments by xzczd, it seems that the `FourierParameters` is not feaible to obtain a non-periodic function defined on any interval.

As inspired by @rmw's `Rescale` method, problem seems to be solved. Thus, now my question changed to "this `Rescale` based method is general enough? What are its limitations?"

**======================= Update 2 ============================**

As kindly suggested by @xzczd in the comments, I double checked the `easyFourier` and find some useful observation.

Beside making Fourier series for an function on genral interval `[a, b]`, the other  motivation for making `easyFourier` by xzczd is that a general form of Fourier series is highly desired,for example,  for solving pdes. In this general form, a symbol parameter `C`, instead of a specific numeric integer, is used to control the order of expansion.

Although, `Rescale` method as shown by rmw can be used to give Fourier for an fucntion on any interval, it can't gives the general form of Fourier series.

**======================= Update 3 ============================**

Now, I think I should give another update. rmw gives such a good answer which shows that `Rescale` method can do what `easyFourier` aimed to do. Do I understand this Right?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What do you find confusing?

Comment: Well, if it can be achieved with `FourierParameter`, I won't have created `easyFourier`… Just read the **Details and Options** section of `FourierSeries`, you'll see it's not possible to `Translate` with `FourierParameter`.

Comment: Is your function periodic? Otherwise you need a Fourier Integral.

Comment: @xzczd: Why is that? Is it beacuse that the specific form of `FourierParameters {a,b}` not general enough? Can't we just use variable change or `Rescale` method as shown by @rmw ? Please, can you show a example whose Fourierseries cannot be obtaiined? Thanks:)

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks for your response. My function is not periodic, and what I want is its Fourier series that approximate in its interval.

Comment: `Rescale` already involves coordinate translation, and this isn't achievable with `FourierParameters`. Once again, please read the **Details and Options** section of `FourierSeries`.

Comment: @xzczd You mean we can't use `FourierParameters` to realize what `Rescale` does, right? Can't we just use `Rescale` for general function defined on any interval? For more clearness, I updated the quesion. Thanks for your helpful comments.

Comment: Please make a bit more effort to edit your question, currently the edited question is just confusing.

Comment: thank you very much. I update my post and I hope it is more clear now. So now my  question becomes is `Rescale` method general enough? I am sure that you must know this method when you make `easyFourier`, then why you made it? Is it becasue `Rescale` method has some its limitations? I had naively think my question is  similar to your question where I find `easyFourier`.

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. Then, please observe the output of `easyFourier` more carefully.

Comment: @xzczd,  I made another update to my post. Please see my update 2,  I understan why `Rescale` method can't solve your problem. Do I understand `easyFourier`  right as stated in update 2? Thanks for your kind and helpful comments.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is stated in [the body of my question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149468/1871) BTW.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks! Sorry for not carfully reading your post :) Have a nice day, sir:)

Comment: @xzczd I think rmw gives a very infromative answer in his respone to my update 2. After all these discussions, I learned a lot from both of you. The Fourier  series in Mathematica will definitely become more and more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func[x_] = Piecewise[{{x, 1 <= x < 2}, {1, 2 <= x <= 3}}];
```

The Fourier functions of Mathematica calculate in the interval [-Pi,Pi] or in case of Sin- and CosSeries in the interval [0, Pi]. To translate the Pi-interval in your function-interval, work with `Rescale`.

```
{\[Pi]Interval, fInterval} = {Rescale[x, {-Pi, Pi}, {1, 3}], Rescale[x, {1, 3}, {-Pi, Pi}]};
fR = FourierTrigSeries[func[x] /. x -> \[Pi]Interval, x, 10] /. x -> fInterval // Simplify;
Plot[fR, {x, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

Supplement because of OP's statement in his 2nd update.

```
cn = FourierCoefficient[func[x] /. x -> \[Pi]Interval, x, n] /.  x -> fInterval;
T = 3 - 1;
a0 = cn[[1, 1, 1]];
an = 2 ComplexExpand@Re@cn[[2]]*Cos[2 \[Pi] n x/T] // Simplify;
bn = -2 ComplexExpand@Im@cn[[2]]*Sin[2 \[Pi] n x/T] // Simplify;

serie = a0 + Inactivate[Sum[Limit[an + bn, n -> k], {k, 1,Infinity]}],  Sum | Limit] // Simplify
```

[image]

```
fPoly = serie /. \[Infinity] -> 20 // Activate;
Plot[fPoly, {x, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wonder that is this `Rescale` based method genral enough for an arbitrary function `f[x]`defined on any interval `[a, b]`?

Comment: @op-luffy Try it! Take any interval [a, b], e.g. [-Pi , 2.5Pi] or something similar.

Comment: @op-luffy Regarding update 2; if you really understood `Rescale`, I don't understand your statement: "...it can't gives the general form of Fourier series."

Comment: Thanks you. @rmw, I have never expected such a beautiful solution! So it can realize what easyFourier aims to do?